# Non-EU citizen married to British citizen, wanting to live in Netherlands

Tags: uk, uk-citizens, netherlands, eu, residency

I am getting married to a British citizen in the next year. We have been in a relationship for 7 years and have been living together for 6 years. We are both living in South Africa.

We would like to move to the Netherlands next year after getting married. How does it work for a NON EU citizen, married to a British citizen, wanting to go settle and work in the Netherlands?

If that is, for some reason, not possible, what would the procedure be for me to relocate to the UK with him (and work there). He has a British passport and I have a South African passport and we both live in South Africa.

Comment: That question belongs at [Expatriates.SE]; this site is for short-term travel rather than settling. However, (a) currently, as a British citizen he has the right to settle in any _other_ EU country as long as he is working (among other cases), and he also has a right to bring his wife to live with him. Expats will know more about how the precise formalities work. (b) Nobody knows yet how things will be after Brexit goes into effect. The freedom-of movement route will almost certainly not be available afterwards; what happens if you have already moved there by then is still anyone's guess.

Comment: Thank you for the info and sorry for posting on the wrong site!